# Laravel GroupBy Issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking for a way to return all fields that match together. For example, I have a player_name column, I'm looking to return all rows where the player names match. One player's name will return a collection of their results, and so on and so on for however many there are.

This is what I have tried so far

```php
$test = DB::table('approved_g_r_p_s')
    ->select('player_name', 'cost')
    ->groupBy('player_name')
    ->get();
```

However it only returned one result from each.

One of player A's fields

One of player B's fields

Despite there being multiple others it has only returned one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you could do the grouping on the PHP side; Collections have a `groupBy` method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add the fields that interest you to the groupBy, something like this:

```
    $test = DB::table('approved_g_r_p_s')
    ->select('player_name', 'cost')
    ->groupBy('player_name', 'cost')
    ->get();
```